# Can't delete database

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and am having a problem with what I perceive to be a simple command `DROP DATABASE` and `DROPDB`. Why would the following commands not delete my database?

```
postgres=# drop database clientms
postgres-# \l
                                    List of databases
   Name    |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 clientms  | clientmsuser | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres     | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres     | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres     | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)

postgres-# dropdb clientms
postgres-# \l
                                    List of databases
   Name    |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 clientms  | clientmsuser | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres     | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres     | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres     | UTF8     | en_GB.UTF-8 | en_GB.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |              |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4 rows)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You forgot the semicolon `;` after the command. Try:

```
DROP DATABASE clientms;
```

The incomplete command is also indicated by the prompt: `-` instead of `=`. This is to allow multi-line commands.

For other cases, not hinging on the simple syntax issue:

- [Dropping DB when there are active connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747282/dropping-db-when-there-are-active-connections/55747694#55747694)

Comment: Yup! People leave it out a lot on the postings on the subject that I've seen :(

Comment: Depending on the client, the semicolon may not be required for a single command. It's required in interactive psql though.

Comment: You can use -S or --single-line to get rid of the required semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

**With PGAdmin:**
Check if you're connected with server, go to your database and right click it and drop the database.
Refresh the database or Re-open the server again!

**Doing it manually:**

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
# \l                         // check db in list
# q                          // to quit that menu
# Drop Database <db_name>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly I'd already solved this problem, then encountered it again a year and a bit later and solved it a different way because I didn't notice that I'd already got notes on how to fix it. Here are my notes:

http://www.itsupportforum.net/topic/unable-to-delete-drop-postgresql-database/

In summary, I couldn't delete the db because it was in use by the interface I was using to delete it. Dumb.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it - **quote the most relevant part of the solution** from the page you're linking to, in case the target page is unavailable. Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `destroydb clientms` works (took me a lot of digging though) [[link]](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPostgreSQL.html)

Comment: No such command. I am guessing you mean `destroydb`, which is the ancient form of the modern day command line tool [`dropdb`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-dropdb.html).

Comment: The difference is that `destroydb` (or rather, the command-line `dropdb` tool) isn't run over the `psql` prompt, but via a unix shell or Windows' cmd.exe. Commands on unix shells and cmd.exe are terminated by a newline, not a semicolon, so you actually ran the command when working on a shell.