# psql appears not to be working

Tags: postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect)

I've just installed the Postgres server and I'm running into a problem using psql. Whenever I'm in the `psql` shell none of the commands have any effect. For example:

```
postgres=# create database testing
postgres=# create user foo
```

It's my understanding that I should see something like this:

```
postgres=# create database testing
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# create user foo
CREATE ROLE
```

The weird thing is I can use the shell commands to make the database and roles.  I've installed postgres from `ppa:pitti/postgresql` on a vanilla install of Ubuntu 10.04 (as per railscast #335).

I've spent a fair amount of time on google trying to figure out what's my problem is but I can't seem to get any answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably not seeing that because you're not finishing the line with a semicolon (;). Your examples should be written as:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE testing;
postgres=# CREATE ROLE foo;
```

Comment: Well, I feel silly now... :P A bit surprised that it didn't complain though.

Comment: @Clay How would it know to complain? It's perfectly valid (and useful) to split SQL statements over several lines for easy editing, readability, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your commands are terminated by the `;`? All statements issued from `psql` should be terminated [by the semicolon](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-4), unless you've specified `-S` switch when invoking `psql`.

Another way to send the query buffer for execution is to issue `\g` meta-command.