# Cannot create database with Postgres on mac

Tags: postgresql

I've just installed 9.5.1 using Homebrew on OSx El Capitan.
I logged in as my user (so I didn't log in with sudo) and it appears that I have the rights to create databases:

```
jamessherry | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS
```

When I list the databases with `\l` I get 4 databases - jamessherry, postgres, template0, template1.

When I then try to create a table with `CREATE DATABASE test`, I get the same 4 databases when I list out again.

Brand new to Postgres, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: probably you forgot to add semicolon `;` at the end of your statement

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213111/psql-appears-not-to-be-working/13213188#13213188

Comment: Freakin' semicolons, man!! XD

Thanks guys. :)