# How to use Postgres SQL database create command?

Tags: postgresql

I am running Postgresql 9.1 on ububtu
I used: psql -d testdb -U postgres
I can see the tables in testdb, among them tables I created earlier, however when trying:
create table newtable(name VARCHAR(10)...);
i get nothing. No CREATE result, and consequently do not see the new table created.

I am new to this db, would appreciate help - what is the problem here?
thnx

Comment: what is the output of the create command? and what is the exact command?

Comment: Check for unterminated strings in your SQL statement and see [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026)

Comment: Copy and paste the *exact text* from your `psql` terminal please.