# postgreSQL.app : create database

Tags: django, postgresql

Hello I'm new in postgreSQL,Please guide me a bit

I have a django project

here is settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    "NAME": "testfor_psl",
    "USER": "",
    "PASSWORD": "",
    "HOST": "localhost",
    "PORT": "",
    }
}
```

And I run `python manage.py syncdb`

There is error:
`OperationalError: FATAL:  database "testfor_psl" does not exist`

So how can I create db??

I use posgreSQL.app, and click the `Open psql`

There is a terminal like this :

I type `help`,and nothing happen.
Please help me. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put `;` at the end of psql commad. As you can see, after command

```
winsome=# CREATE DATABASE testfor_psl
```

the prompt is changed from `=#` to `-#`. It means, that psql still wait for the command to be completed by providing `;`.

Also, it is better to create  a database user for django project. So here what you need to do:

1. Create user in database (in psql):

   ```
   CREATE USER testfor_psl_user WITH password 'pass';
   ```
2. Create database with owner equals to that user:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE testfor_psl ENCODING 'UTF8' TEMPLATE template0 OWNER testfor_psl_user;
   ```
3. Set credentials in django project settings:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
   "default": {
       "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
       "NAME": "testfor_psl",
       "USER": "testfor_psl_user",
       "PASSWORD": "pass",
       "HOST": "localhost",
       "PORT": "5432",  # default port
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks really help!!Btw is postgreSQL.app just a terminal ?? I mean,is there a GUI I can see the db ??

Comment: @user2492364 yes, psql is terminal-like command interface to postgres. And yes, there is a [pgadmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/), that provides a GUI

Answer (score 1):

The reason `help` had no effect is that you were already in the middle of writing a command. **SQL commands must be terminated by a semicolon**. Pay attention to the `psql` prompt - see how it changed from `=#` to `-#`? That indicates you're in the middle of a command. See [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12472026/398670) .

If you weren't halfway though a command, typing `help` would've shown:

```
mydbname=> help
You are using psql, the command-line interface to PostgreSQL.
Type:  \copyright for distribution terms
       \h for help with SQL commands
       \? for help with psql commands
       \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query
       \q to quit
```

Now... [here's the manual for the `psql` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

For summary help on `psql` its self use `\?` .

For a listing of SQL commands use `\h`.

For help on specific commands use `\h COMMAND NAME` e.g. `\h CREATE DATABASE` to see how to use the `CREATE DATABASE` command. For more details on a command read the manual, e.g. [the manual on `CREATE DATABASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html).

[Here's the PostgreSQL tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html), which covers getting started.