# In postgresql: CREATE ROLE works but createuser doesn't

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and was following [this](https://www.codementor.io/engineerapart/getting-started-with-postgresql-on-mac-osx-are8jcopb) tutorial. I can create roles just fine but when I tried to use the `createuser` and `dropuser` commands, it just doesn't do anything and no new users are created or any deleted. I tried to use it with and without the semi colon at the end, the former gives a syntax error and the latter just doesn't do anything.

```
    postgres-# createuser joe;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createuser"
LINE 1: createuser 
        ^
postgres=# ;
postgres=# createuser joe;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "createuser"
LINE 1: createuser joe;
        ^
postgres=# createuser joe
postgres-# \du
                                   List of roles
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 admin     | Superuser, Create DB                                       | {}
 john      | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication             | {}
 guest     |                                                            | {}
 guest3    |                                                            | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I also tried this:

```
createuser --interactive joe
```

This also didn't do anything.

What's the correct way to use `createuser`? I'm using the following version.

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 11.1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inside the `psql` tool you need to enter SQL commands. To create a user from SQL, you need to use [`create user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html).

The tutorial probably was running the command line utility `createuser` (not the SQL  command)

To understand why:

```
postgres=# createuser joe
```

did not do anything, see: [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect)

Comment: Okay, I might have misunderstood the tutorial. I thought it meant that the utility came with the package and tried to use both in psql and command line. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 8):

I think you need a space between your command, something like the following:

```
CREATE USER youruser WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'yourpass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE yourdbname TO youruser;
```

Answer (score 3):

Command createuser need to run in console(bash). No need to do it in psql.
Example:

```
createuser -h localhost -p 5432 joe
```

Answer (score 0):

is created by the postgres user in the console above:

```sql
createuser joe
```