# After some commands terminal doesn't allow to write

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, terminal, psql, pager

I learn from tutorials, often when they type commands in terminal and press enter, the operation is executed and they can type next command. I often get stuck on these screens (often ctlr+c helps, but on the image below doesn't).

[image]

Commands like `\l`, `service postgresql status` do that.

Can anybody explain why people in tutorials don't have that and how do I exit these things?

Comment: Anybody? Can't do a thing after \l in psql

Comment: This maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026

Comment: `service postgresql status` is **not** a `psql` (or SQL) command, but a Linux command. You can't run that inside psql. Your screenshot shows the output of a command displayed through the pager. The pager is typically ended by pressing `q`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are "stuck" in the pager `less`. Try typing `q` to get back to the `psql` prompt.

Whenever a result set is to long or too wide for the screen, `psql` will call the configured pager to paginate the result set.

You can disable this feature with

```
\pset pager off
```

on the `psql` prompt or in your `~/.psqlrc` file.