# Postgres "Did not find any relation named <tablename>"

Tags: postgresql

I created a new database in Postgres (Ubuntu 18.04) and created a table from the Postgres command line with:

```
CREATE TABLE TMB01
```

the command line returns with no error messages.  Then I created columns from the command line (one by one, but I only had four columns names to enter).

Now I want to see the names of all tables in my database:

```
\d+ "TMB01"
```

"Did not find any relation named "TMB01."

Try it without quotes:

```
\d+ TMB01
```

"Did not find any relation named "TMB01."

Then I tried:

```
select * from TMB01 where false
```

No error message, cursor returns.

What went wrong with my table creation?

Comment: What does the query report without the condition ? Might be the optimizer kicking in and producing the empty resultset.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by condition

Comment: the where clause.

Comment: It returns to the cursor without reporting any error.  There is no data in the table yet, maybe that's why?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the **complete** statements you have run. Copy and paste the complete output of your `psql` session to your question. `CREATE TABLE TMB01` is an invalid statement to begin with. Typically you also don add columns "one by one", but include them right in the `create table` statement.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you didn't get an error with this command:

```
CREATE TABLE TMB01
```

Is that it wasn't finished yet.  There's no ; at the end.  At a minimum you would need:

```
CREATE TABLE TMB01 ();
```

Comment: I'm working from the command line, so I don't think the semi is needed.  Here is what I did:  CREATE TABLE TMB02 (); and Postgres responds:  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ADD" and a second line:  LINE1:  ADD COLUMN EMail, text

Comment: It is definitely needed.  Try disconnecting and re-connecting to make sure your history is clear and try it again.  The command CREATE TABLE TMB02(); failed because it was interpreted as part of some previous ALTER TABLE statement that was never properly terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Try granting access privileges to the postgres user [grant wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NufjH.png)