# PostgreSQL commands don't work until I try and run them again in psql shell

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

When I try to run a command in the psql shell, it doesn't work and I have to enter it again. For example, if I run `SELECT * FROM flights;`, it won't run and says

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 2: SELECT * FROM flights;
        ^
```

But, when I try it again, it works completely fine. Help!
I'm using the windows version.

(It only works some times)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` doesn't run the query when you hit "enter", it runs the query when it sees a semicolon. You're getting this error because you forgot the semicolon in the *previous* query.

For example:

```
test=> select 1
test-> select 1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select 1;
        ^
```

The query sent to the server is `select 1 select 1`, hence the syntax error on `LINE 2`.

The hint that you're in the middle of an unterminated command is the terminal prompt, which changes from `test=>` to `test->` after the first line.