# Loading sample database into Postgres

Tags: postgresql

first time user.

I purchased a book called SQL for Data Analytics and it comes with a dump file ("data.dump") (link below).

https://github.com/TrainingByPackt/SQL-for-Data-Analytics/tree/master/Datasets

The book advised installing PostgreSQL which I have done and then loading the dump file via command line (see image below).

For some reason, I am able to create the database via command line (it appears in pgAdmin) but nothing happens when I load the dump file.

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE sqlda TEMPLATE template0;

postgres=# psql < /Users/ast12/Documents/data.dump
```

I have also tried loading the dump file directly via pgAdmin. Again, nothing happens. I'm at a total loss. I bought the book to learn but with my limited knowledge, I can't even set up the environment to do so. 
enter image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR7lY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already inside the `psql` prompt, there is no need to call or run `psql` again.

After you created the database, you need to switch to it, then run the SQL script using the command `\i`

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE sqlda;
postgres=# \connect sqlda 
postgres=# \i /Users/ast12/Documents/data.dump
```

`\connect sqlda` changes to the newly created database, and `\i` loads and runs the SQL script.

For an explanation on why nothing happened for your second command, see [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks. That was the help I needed. I'm all set up now. Took seconds. Much appreciated.