# PostgreSQL Create Table command not working, checked access privileges and all default privileges are there

Tags: postgresql

I'm extremely new to PostgreSQL and I just installed it using Homebrew.

I ran through creating and connecting to a database and now I'm trying to create a table with the standard command `CREATE TABLE users(name string, age smallint, birthday date)` and the command completes. However as soon as I run the command to list all tables I get the following `Did not find any relations`.

I checked all users and privileges and it looks like my profiles roles include `Superuser, Create Role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS` and I'm a member of `{}`.

I'm not sure if there's something more I need to do in order to create tables under a certain database or not, but I've looked all over and can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: The command could not possibly have completed.  There is no `string` datatype.  Where are you executing the commands?  Did you terminate your statement with a `;`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/)?

Comment: Ah that was it, it was a syntax error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what you're intending to do, be more explicit.
But it seems to me you've juste created tables and did not create any relations.
Try using a key and defining mother tables ?