# Changing the column header of a table in a postgres database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to rename a column in my database.

I did

```
heroku pg:psql

ALTER TABLE discounts_discount RENAME COLUMN percentagediscountm TO percentagediscount
```

And that had no impact. I looked on a few sites and to the best of my knowledge, what I wrote above should work.

[image]

I tried making the change using make migrations and migrate but then got this error.

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: discounts.discount has no field named 'percentagediscountm'
```

[image]

I am really trying to avoid having to drop my database or rolling back Heroku to an earlier build.

Comment: Don't do manual changes to your database structure if you want to keep the migrations in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enter the same command with `;` at the end. That should work:

```
ALTER TABLE discounts_discount RENAME COLUMN percentagediscountm TO percentagediscount;
```

You can see [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect) to get the detail knowledge on how it was not working.