# Can't find pg_dump generated file after running on Google Cloud SQL server

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, psql

I ran:

```
psql "sslmode=disable dbname=postgres user=postgres hostaddr=[INSTANCE_IP]"
```

- yes I put my google cloud instant's IP here and authed just fine and got to the postgres prompt

Then I ran this:

```
pg_dumpall --schema-only > ~/grinds/desktop/definitiononly.sql
```

`grinds` is my OS X laptop

but I don't see the `definitiononly.sql` file anywhere in OS X.  Was it created on the server??  I didn't think so, pretty sure it should output to my PC.

Same thing happened when I used the Google Cloud Console:

[image]

The operation did nothing after I hit enter so I assumed it worked but can't tell

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026

Answer (score 0):

pg_dump is a program.  It is run from the Linux command line (eg bash), not the SQL command line (eg psql).  You would have gotten a syntax error, except psql allows multiline commands that are ended by a semicolon and a newline, not by just a newline.