# PSQL does not display query output

Tags: psql

I have connected to my PSQL database from the command line. However, when I run commands like `\dt`, or any other query for that matter, I simply don't get any output. It simply returns `my_database=>`

```
my_database=> \dt
my_database=> \dn
my_database=> select * from table limit 1;
my_database=>
```

`\x` does not help. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/

Comment: No, it's not about terminating with a semicolon. Using `\r` does not help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be that you have redirected standard output to a file with the `\o filename` command. Use `\o` without an argument to get the output on the console again.