# psql --help not displaying any result

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am new to Postgresql. I am using SQL shell (psql) for interacting with the database. When I use psql commands, it is not displaying any output. I am using psql(13.3) version.
When I use psql --help, as per documentation, it should display the available options. But I didnt get any output displayed. Similarly when I use another command starting with psql, it is  not displaying any results.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Did you use `--help` as option when you *called* `psql` in the (user) shell (from the OS) or did you try to use it as command *after* `psql` has *already started* in its own CLI?

Comment: If you already _started_ `psql` (and see the prompt) you need to enter `\?` or `help` to display the help. (which is what `psql` actually told you after it was started: "*Type "help" for help.*"

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect?r=SearchResults&s=1|95.8217

Comment: @stickybit I was using psql own CLI

Comment: @ElanchezianR: The `--help` is the wrong input at that stage. See @a_horse_with_no_name's comment(s) on what to use then.

Comment: See here: https://i.imgur.com/JP6c2nR.png

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add postgresql to the environment variables. \bin & \lib

C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib