# pg_ctl command gives no reponse on Ubuntu 20.04 Postgres14

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql, pg-ctl

Im new to Ubuntu, Accessing something like pg_ctl wont work. Whats the problem here? Is it not installed? Or is it something else? Would really appreciate some help

```
Guy@GuyLinux:~$ sudo -i -u postgres
[sudo] password for guy: 
postgres@GuyLinux:~$ psql
psql (14.1 (Ubuntu 14.1-1.pgdg20.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# pg_ctl status
```

Returns no response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_ctl` is a shell command, not a Postgres command.  You enter it at the shell prompt (`$`), not in the `psql` utility.