# Why a request for a field value in a database table inside docker container returns empty value?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I need to connect to a postgres database and view the contents of one of the tables. No problem to connect, I do it this way

```
sudo docker-compose exec db psql -p 5432 -d gpanel_db -U db_root
```

where

```
db - service name in docker-compose file

gpanel_db - DB name

db_root - DB user
```

Connecting to DB

```
use gpanel_db
```

Show tables

```
gpanel_db=# \dt

                          List of relations
 Schema |                   Name                   | Type  |  Owner  
--------+------------------------------------------+-------+---------
 public | auth_group                               | table | db_root
 public | auth_group_permissions                   | table | db_root
 public | auth_permission                          | table | db_root
 public | auth_user                                | table | db_root
 public | auth_user_groups                         | table | db_root
 public | auth_user_user_permissions               | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_creativecategory      | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_creativestatushistory | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_creativetag           | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_creativetype          | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_googlecreative        | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_googlecreativespend   | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_playablecreativesize  | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_tag                   | table | db_root
 public | creative_performer_videocreativeduration | table | db_root
 public | django_admin_log                         | table | db_root
 public | django_content_type                      | table | db_root
 public | django_migrations                        | table | db_root
 public | django_session                           | table | db_root
 public | django_site                              | table | db_root
```

But `select name from auth_group` return nothing, just starts a new line

Same behaviour for several other tables I have queried

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing semicolon ";" at the end of the instruction.

Comment: how silly, I tried with ; but without a space and got a syntax error.