# postgres not letting me make a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Why isn't the database there?

```
postgres=# CREATE USER pavankat WITH PASSWORD 'dfjjelkfjls'
postgres-# CREATE database datathing
postgres-# GRANT RULE ON datathing to pavankat
postgres-# \c lateral-dev
FATAL:  database "lateral-dev" does not exist
Previous connection kept


 which psql
/usr/bin/psql
```

I have postgres 9.1

I'm using it for a rails application with ruby 2.0 and rails 4.0 and I'm on a computer running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (32 bit)

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/10912697/398670

Comment: Nope not the same thing. Thanks for down voting my question. If you're trying to create a database. You're definitely not looking deleting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needed a semicolon at the end. Like this:

```
CREATE database datathing;
```