# CREATE and DROP database won't work

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want simply drop some databases and after that create a new one.

Within postgresql version 9.1, running these commands first to create:

```
postgres=# createdb [dbname]
```

or

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE name
```

as described here [Postgresql Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdatabase.html).

Now, to drop away some databases:

```
postgres=# DROP DATABASE name
```

as described here as well [Postgresql Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-dropdatabase.html).

They all didn't work. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you have to be a superuser

Comment: When I log into postgre I log using sudo -u postgres pqsl, then enter my password. Do you mean that?

Comment: @Randy, no Randy. When typing those commands nothing happens. No error messages, no warnings, no nothing.

Comment: You need to terminate the commands with a `;` (and `createdb` is **not** a SQL statement, it's an operating system program)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Missing the colon omg!!! That worked! Incredible how we don't think in any possibilities before going out asking. Thanks mate. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the semicolons.

```
postgres=# DROP DATABASE name;
```

SQL commands may carry on over multiple lines, and are only sent to the server when you end them with a semicolon. That's why the prompt changes:

```
postgres=# DROP DATABASE name
postgres-#
```

It might be a good idea to take a look through the tutorial.

Additionally `createdb` isn't an SQL command. It's a shell utility command that wraps `CREATE DATABASE` for convenience.

See also:

- [Can't delete database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10912697/398670)
- [In psql, why do some commands have no effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472026/in-psql-why-do-some-commands-have-no-effect)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to be a superuser because accroding to the documentation :

**for create a new database :**

> To create a database, you must be a superuser or have the special
>   CREATEDB privilege. See [CREATE USER](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createuser.html).

**for drop a database**

> DROP DATABASE drops a database. It removes the catalog entries for the
>   database and deletes the directory containing the data. **It can only be
>   executed by the database owner**.

Read this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_create_database.htm), it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in answering my question. This tutorial helped! Thanks!

Comment: @NiceGuy : If my answer helped you, so validate it, in order to help someone else

Comment: That advice would be useful, but does not answer the question correctly. The problem is totally different; see my answer.